# FastReports: Add Querys Data Tab without Database connection from Client Side

Tags: delphi, reporting, fastreport, multi-tier

I have a multi-tier application made in Delphi XE3.

At client side, I have a report made with FastReports associated to a TClientDataSet with the main data, but I need to add querys in TFrxReport's Data Tab for get data from detail tables. I can't add those querys on the app because the end user is who select that details on runtime and it would can be many details. I need add that details dinamicly.

The question is, ¿Is possible add querys inside TFrxReport's component Data Tab without a database connection on Client Side? or ¿Do I need to add a Database Connection definitely?.

Best Regards

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Don't you want to just connect your client dataset with a `TfrxDBDataset` through the `DataSet` property and add it to the report data sources as usually (through the menu item _Report / Data_ in the report designer)?

Comment: I need add some queries on Data Tab inside TFrxReport, the way that you quote is the normal way that I use when develop a Report, but I need other data that the END USER can add, but I don't want create a database connection on client side, FastReport allows do queries inside report, but it needs a database connection

Comment: Aha, I think I got what you want. You want to let the user who will design the report write a SQL command to query data (actually dataset fields) from the linked client dataset. Hm, I don't think you can do that without a connection. Besides executing SQL command against (in-memory table) client dataset is not possible as it's missing a SQL engine provider.

Comment: the is a way, but I have to write some components, at FastReport's Developer Manual at page 23, there's an example that shows how to write your own DB Engine like FrxADOComponents or FrxIBXComponents